# Alternative commands for chkconfig in ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm a new to linux platform. I need to establish mongodb as a start-up service. In fedora, I was able to run following commands and successfully did the task.

```
chkconfig —add mongodb
chkconfig mongodb on
```

But in ubuntu 13.10, this chkconfig command is not available. I found the `update-rc.d`command is an alternative for that. But I'm still unable to execute those cammands. How can I achieve this task in ubuntu ?

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to Fedora the services that are installed on an Ubuntu system are enabled by default, so you don't need to add or enable them to the init system.

You can check the service status with:
$ service mongodb status

On 12.04 LTS the 10gen mongodb package provides integration into the upstart init system provided in Ubuntu, you can find the job file in /etc/init/mongodb.conf

Comment: I didn't install mongodb from software center(apt-get). I only got the tar.gz file and setted the path. Then I manually created /etc/init/mongodb.conf file with all configurations as in [link]http://ewan.im/15/mongodb-initd-script

Comment: /etc/init is the location of upstart configuration files, not system v init files. The file you copied is for system v, which belong to /etc/init.d and usually don't have a .conf suffix. From this I take that your knowledge in Ubuntu configuration is limited and would advise you to try out the already built and integrated packages from 10gen.